# Are the line breaks allowed in the PGF 3.0 tree graph nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

The node/child layout of the trees allows to break node text into multiple lines.
I tried the same with graph but luaLatex compilation never completed (using Texmaker) and I had to stop it, which produced errors such as `Undefined control sequence \\`

Is it possible to break node text with graphs too?

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees, layered}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [
    binary tree layout,
    sibling distance=4mm,
    level distance=8mm,
    components go right top aligned,
    component sep=1pt,
    nodes=draw
]
{
    Supervisor
    -- Current Employee %\\ Current Employee Position
        -- {
            Subordinate 1--{Worker 01,Worker 02},
            Subordinate 2--{SubSubordinate 21--{Worker 21,Worker 22,Worker 23}
        },
        Subordinate 3-- SubSubordinate01--{Worker 11,Worker 12}
    };
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above MWE works, but if I removed the comment, it would not...

The purpose of this MWE is to avoid having to do lots of node size and position calculations for the org chart I am working on.

EDIT:

Just to clarify, it seems that node text in the graph layout is directly used as a node name for the purposes of linking nodes together, aligning layers/levels etc, thus new lines and even comas break the compilation.

It appears as graph layout is in very beta state at the moment, usable only for the very simplistic one-two word nodes with no punctuation involving new lines or comas :(

I'll try to bring this to Till's attention on Sourceforge, let's see what comes out of that.

Comment: try enclosing it in braces, perhaps

Comment: Nope :( Same error. I guess that has to do with the fact that in graphs node text is also node name for all purposes... I even tried putting a node in there to no avail. Ultimately, I wanted to be able to include pictures into the graph nodes, but this seems to be not supported.

Comment: Ah, that actually makes a lot of sense.  I'm not really an expert in the graph drawing library, but I don't think there is a way to get around this limitation yet.  I may *very* well be wrong, though :)

Comment: Yes, seeing how graph drawing library made its way into PGF from a student's thesis, it is no surprise that this technology is in the emerging state at the moment. There should be separate node name and node text at the very least for this to be versatile and useful. Still an amazing technology for which credit is due!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
"Current Employee \\ Current Employee Position"[align=center]
```

or

```
CE[as={Current Employee \\ Current Employee Position},align=center]
```

or

```
CE/"Current Employee \\ Current Employee Position"[align=center]
```

where `CE` is the node name.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees, layered}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [
    binary tree layout,
    sibling distance=4mm,
    level distance=8mm,
    components go right top aligned,
    component sep=1pt,
    nodes=draw
]
{
    Supervisor
    -- CE[as={Current Employee \\ Current Employee Position},align=center]
        -- {
            Subordinate 1--{Worker 01,Worker 02},
            Subordinate 2--{SubSubordinate 21--{Worker 21,Worker 22,Worker 23}
        },
        Subordinate 3-- SubSubordinate01--{Worker 11,Worker 12}
    };
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can also insert an Image side by side to this node text:

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees, layered}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{mwe}% example image

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [
    binary tree layout,
    sibling distance=4mm,
    level distance=8mm,
    components go right top aligned,
    component sep=1pt,
    nodes=draw
]
{
    Supervisor
    -- CE[as={%
          \begin{varwidth}[b]{.5\linewidth}
            \centering Current Employee \\ Current Employee Position
          \end{varwidth}
          \includegraphics[height=1.5\baselineskip]{example-image}}
       ]
        -- {
            Subordinate 1--{Worker 01,Worker 02},
            Subordinate 2--{SubSubordinate 21--{Worker 21,Worker 22,Worker 23}
        },
        Subordinate 3-- SubSubordinate01--{Worker 11,Worker 12}
    };
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Where is this documented? Is it possible to include the images into the nodes similarly?

Comment: In the pgfmanual ;-) The Option `as=` for example on page 270.

Comment: `includegraphics` seems to work, but not `being figure`

Comment: @ajeh Do you mean `\begin{figure}..\end{figure}`? Why would you want to use a floating environment inside a tree? (In other words: Don't. Just add `\includegraphics{image}` directly, as you have already found that works.)

Comment: Yes. That kind of works, but has undesirable side effects, such as I can only resort to having image above or below node text, but not side by side :( That takes up extra vertical space on a page.

Comment: @ajeh I have added an example with an image side by side to the text in this node.